# Program crashes with the error “Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 111” (linux beginner)

Tags: linux-mint, error-handling

This is my first time posting, so I'm sorry for any mistakes in formating or exposing the problem. I am also a Linux beginner.

I am trying to run a bioinformatics program called Caver Analyst. Whenever I call it on the terminal, I get the following output:

```
dgesto@jarvis ~: caver_analyst

Jul 24, 2019 5:24:39 PM cz.caver.Main main
INFO: Using default userdir: /home/dgesto/.caver_analyst/2.0b2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/usr/local/lib/caver_analyst2/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 111: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 (Tessa) with OpenJDK version 11.0.3. I thought it might have somethig to do with java, and tried downgrading to version 8 with no luck.

If you need anymore information about my system please let me know.

Comment: Hi, not sure this will be of help, but here's a related Launchpad [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sweethome3d/+bug/1797920) with the same problem with another Java app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it, it really was a problem with some java update. I purged OpenJDK 11 following [these instructions](https://novicestuffs.wordpress.com/2017/04/25/how-to-uninstall-java-from-linux/) and installed OpenJDK 8. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to purge OpenJDK from my box, so you can download Oracle JDK 8 from Oracle and run the following command:

```
$ PATH=<oracle_jdk_path>/bin:$PATH JDK_HOME=<oracle_jdk_path> ./caver_analyst
```